# Wrong detection of screen height on iPhone 8 XCode 9

Tags: ios, iphone, screen

I am working on an app and for some reason when I test it on my iPhone 8 the height of my screen is wrongly detected: `self.view.bounds.height` (or even `UIScreen.main.bounds.height`) returns 568.0 instead of 667.0. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Is there a problem with my iPhone? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using a launch screen storyboard? Most likely not and you don't have all of the proper launch images either. You need one or the other.

Comment: No I am not using the launch screen storyboard, just the main storyboard for now... however the screen detection works correctly on all the simulators and on an old iPhone 6S. The only device which seems to have this problem is the iPhone 8.

Comment: So it works with an iPhone 8 simulator but not a specific real iPhone 8, correct? Then perhaps the iPhone 8 is setup to run in "zoom" mode.

Comment: Yes it's not working only on my iPhone 8. I checked Settings/General/Accessibility/Zoom and it's set to off... is there anything else I should check? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Settings -> General -> Display & Brightness -> View

Comment: Awesome that was it! Thank you!